# Is a set5 is countable if we can found a bijection between the set and a subset of natural number?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A be a an infinite set.

Let B be a subset of N, where N is the natural number

Say there is a one to one correspondent between A and B. However, B is not the whole natural number. B is only a subset of a natural number.

Intuitively, this is very clear. N is even "bigger" than A.

However, how to go from that to actually finding out that there is a one to one correspondence between A and N?

Basically I am checking several different definition of countably infinite. One requires a one to one bijection between A and N. The other requires only an injection from A to N. The latter seems to be a weaker requirement.

Comment: If you have an infinite set $A$, you can always inject $\mathbb{N}$ into $A$. If $A$ also injects into $\mathbb{N}$, then $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are bijective by the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroder theorem.

Comment: There is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. But in practice it is more convenient to use the Schroder-Bernstein theorem: if there is an injection from A to B and an injection from B to A, then they have the same cardinality.

Comment: proof? I want formal proof. That is the question. He he he he

Comment: You have the name of theorem, google can now answer more questions than us. (It's not the easiest proof by the way)

Comment: In set theory the term "countable" has two different meaning. It may denote a set that has a *bijection* between the set and $\Bbb{N}$. However some people use the term "countable" to denote a set which is *finite or equipotent to $\Bbb{N}$*.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly if there is a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$, then there is an one-to-one function from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ given by the same function.

Suppose now that $h:A\to B$ is a one-to-one function, with $B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$. One first step is to prove that $B$ is infinite, but this follows from the fact that there is no a one-to-one function from an infinite set to a finite one (pigeonhole principle)

Consider the following sequence of elements, defined inductively:

$$b_0=\min B, \hspace{1cm}b_{k+1}=\min (B\setminus \{b_1,\ldots,b_k\}) $$

This is well-defined since $B\setminus \{b_1,\ldots,b_k\}$ is always a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

*Claim: $B=\{b_0,b_1,\ldots\}$*

*Proof of the Claim:* Clearly $\{b_0,b_1,\ldots\}\subseteq B$ since every $b_i$ is an element from $B$. For the other direction, notice that if $k\in B$, then one of the elements $b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_k$ must be equal to $k$. (I leave this as an exercise). $\square$.

Now, notice that the function $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to A$ defined by $\phi(k)=h^{-1}(b_k)$ is bijective. Thus, $\phi^{-1}:A\to \mathbb{N}$ is the required map.

Comment: I once overheard that  the countable case is the only "infinite case" of the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem that is possible to prove without any further assumption (such as axiom of choice), but I am not sure about this assertion.

Comment: if k∈B, then one of the elements b0,b1,…,bk must be equal to k. (I leave this as an exercise). pigeon hole principle?

Comment: @JimThio Exactly! Worst case scenario you will have that the sequence $b_0<b_1<\cdots<b_k$ is exactly the sequence $0<1<\cdots<k$.